# How to Display high score using GUIText

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

Well, i'm pretty new with unity. I got a problem to display highscore. The score was display everytime enemy were shot. I want to display the highscore everytime the game end and be able to update everytime i got a new highscore. The score system using the GUI text. The example below.

Score:

Highscore:

To display the score, i'm using this script

```
using UnityEngine;

public class HealthScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int hp = 1;
    private GUIText scoreReference;
    public bool isEnemy = true;

    public void Damage(int damageCount)
    {
        hp -= damageCount;

        if (hp <= 0)
        {
            // Dead!
            Destroy(gameObject);
            scoreReference.text = (int.Parse(scoreReference.text) + 1).ToString();
        }
    }

    void Start()
    {
        scoreReference = GameObject.Find("Score").guiText;
    }

    // . . .
}
```

i got some idea to retrieve the value of the score, but it won't display. Please help me.. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this will be good

```
get { if (_highscore == -1) 
        _highscore = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Highscore", 0);
        return _highscore; 
    }
    set {
        if (value > _highscore) {
            _highscore = value;
            highscoreReference.text = _highscore.ToString();
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Highscore", _highscore);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

we put a isDead boolaen and make it **true** when the **player** dies and when isDead is true we will show the score

```
int score; 
int highscore;
bool isDead=false;
```

//initilizing

```
 void OnGUI () {
    if(isDead) //make this true when player dies
        GUI.Label (new Rect (0,0,100,50),score.ToString());
    }
void Awake(){
       highscore=PlayerPrefs.GetInt("highscore");
 }

public void Damage(int damageCount)
    {
        hp -= damageCount;

        if (hp <= 0)
        {
            // Dead!
            Destroy(gameObject);
            score++;  //increase score
            if(score>highscore)
               highscore=score;
        }
    }
public void onGameEnds(){
  PlayerPrefs.SetInt("highscore",highscore);
}
```

Comment: yeah..that will show the point, but i need the highscore, the highscore can be update.